# Python web-scraping not being able to display .css files when local hosting the webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make a copy of a website, which copy I can then localhost. The problem is that the CSS is not loading and I am getting only the raw HTML. I tried fixing it by messing with the file names but to no avail.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os
import re


url = "https://prompt.ml/0"
folder = "Website"
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, features='lxml')

def Downloader(url, folder):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))
    os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folder))    
    
    images = soup.find_all('img')
    css = soup.find_all('link')


    for image in images:
        link = image['src']
        name = os.path.basename(link)

        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            im = requests.get(link)
            f.write(im.content)

    for result in css:
        lol = result['href']
        name1 = os.path.basename(lol)
        try:
            with open(name1, 'wb') as f:
                Lmao = requests.get(lol)
                f.write(Lmao.content)
        except:
            continue
    
    reg = re.compile(r'https://prompt.ml')

    soup1 = (reg.sub('Website', str(soup)))
    soup1 = bytes(soup1,'utf-8')

    with open(folder +'.html', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(soup1)
    return soup1



Downloader(url=url, folder=folder)
```

In the first two lines of the function, I make a directory that will store the files.
Then I download the images and CSS. On this website, there are no images.
My results are:

```
/bootstrap.min.css
/flat-ui.css
/font-awesome.min.css
/styles.css
```

And then the part where I think my mistake is at.

```
 reg = re.compile(r'https://prompt.ml')

    soup1 = (reg.sub('Website', str(soup)))
    soup1 = bytes(soup1,'utf-8')
```

Here I remove the URL from all the links from the website and replace it with `Website`, which is the name of the folder. But for some reason when I open the HTML document. I am greeted with ugly HTML and no CSS whatsoever. Please whoever is reading this, please help I've been stuck on this for a week and a half, please I beg you.

Answer (score 0):

The site uses resources from other sites/apis such as `bootstrap`, `fontawesome`, `jquery` and `cloudflare cdn`.

If you want the site to be completely offline, you need to download all of them and store them.

For example:
font awesome it downloaded from:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

so you would want to download it and store it using the relative path:

```
/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

So remember to change the path in the HTML file.

Repeat this for all the resources, and it should work.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response but I ran into a problem. I get the relative path of the file with this code `name = os.path.relpath(image_url)` , but Python doesn't allow characters like `/` as a filename. So I thought  that I can simply run a .replace command `name =  name.replace("/", "")` but I am not exactly sure if this is the way I should approach the problem. Also, the HTML uses `/` so I am stuck again. Sorry for making it so difficult

Comment: The problem is that `/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` is not a valid filename. And doing something like `font-awesome4.3.0cssfont-awesome.min.css` or `-font-awesome-4.3.0-css-font-awesome.min.css` makes it so it couldn't be displayed as the HTML file doesn't get linked to the correct file.

Comment: @Yasmine3333 You may want to try [pywebcopy](https://pypi.org/project/pywebcopy/), a python library designed for it.

Comment: Using pywebcopy is the obvious thing, but I want to complete the whole project with the script. Thanks for the suggetion tho!